# How do I create Virtual Applications/Folders with Azure Resource Manager Templates?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager

I'm trying to create an ARM template to stamp out multiple instances of our fairly simple Web App product.

I'm struggling to add a Virtual Application to my web app.  i.e. something like this :-

[image: Web App Virtual Folder]

But I can't find the right JSON to achieve this.  I found the following sample online but it doesn't appear to have any effect.

(under properties for the Web Application)

```
"virtualApplications": [
              {
                "virtualPath": "/",
                "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot"
              },
              {
                "virtualPath": "/virtualApp",
                "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot\\virtualApp"
              }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The settings are under the web config. So in your ARM template, you just have to add another resource (along side the site resource) as follows:

```
{
    "apiVersion": "2014-06-01",
    "name": "web",
    "type": "config",
    "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web\/sites\/', parameters('siteName'))]"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "virtualApplications": [
            {
                "virtualPath": "\/",
                "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot",
                "preloadEnabled": false,
                "virtualDirectories": null
            },
            {
                "virtualPath": "\/virtualApp",
                "physicalPath": "site\\wwwroot\\virtualApp",
                "preloadEnabled": false,
                "virtualDirectories": null
            }
        ],
        // other web config settings i.e.
        "phpVersion": "5.4"
    }
}
```

Comment: See also [here](https://github.com/davidebbo/AzureWebsitesSamples/blob/aa75b8a5780dfb81b5ae47624958884c324e4aa0/ARMTemplates/WebAppManyFeatures.json#L71-L80) for complete template sample.

Comment: Ah ha!   I had the correct code - but in the wrong place.  I'd put all that stuff directly within the /sites node.

Many thanks - all working now.